# JS: Convert Variable Value Into String Literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just found myself in a little catch-22. I'm trying to make a React component that renders code. Basically, a `pre` node that I can wrap in line numbering, syntax highlighting, etc. However, I'm stuck at the very beginning.

How do I pass a code snippet to `props.children` and then render it in the component? Heres the basic setup:

```
<CodeBlock>
    <div>Hello Hackers!</div>
</CodeBlock>


export const CodeBlock = (props) => {
    return(
        <pre>
            {props.children}
        </pre>
    );
}
// This evaluates as a rendered div


export const CodeBlock = (props) => {
    return(
        <pre>
            {`props.children`}
        </pre>
    );
}
// This evaluates literally as `props.children`


<CodeBlock>
    {`<div>Hello Hackers!</div>`}
</CodeBlock>
// This works but it's messy for the end-user
```

Comment: So are we to guess now what "messy" could be in this case? Ignoring your text and just replying to your question title: `variable.toString()`

Comment: The generic ways to turn something into a string in JS are [`value.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) or (for serializing and pretty-printing) [`JSON.stringify(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Sorry, the messy comment had a typo that made it unclear. What I meant was that the user would have to remember to wrap their code in curly braces and back ticks.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. Can't wait to try them when I get home. If somebody will post this as an answer instead of a comment I can mark it correct.

Comment: FWIW, `variable.toString()` does not work in this situation because the contents of the string are already evaluated as objects by the time it gets to the point I can touch it. Then, `this.props.children.toString()` just evaluates to `[object Object]`. Wrapping the inner code block with curly braces and backticks is messy but is the only way I can find to accomplish this so far.